# Пытаюсь понять из-за чего ошибка IndexError с базой данных

Tags: python, telebot, pymysql

Использую библиотеку telebot и pymysql. Мне нужно при нажатии кнопки зарегистрировать пользователя в бд и проверить на подписку. Но ИНОГДА вылетает ошибка IndexError. Я не понять из-за чего, если данные которые я получаю не пустые и там есть информация, которая мне нужна. Сам код:

```
def register(m):
    con = POOL.connection()
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = %s LIMIT 1', (m.from_user.id,))
    data = cur.fetchall()
    if data == ():
        cur.execute('REPLACE INTO users (user_id, username, user_sub, user_data)'
                    'VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)', (m.from_user.id, m.from_user.username, config.user_sub,
                                               config.user_data,))
        con.commit()
        cur.close()
        con.close()


def get_info(m):
    con = POOL.connection()
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = %s LIMIT 1', (m.from_user.id,))
    data = cur.fetchall()
    user_sub = data[0][3]
    user_data_check = data[0][4]
    cur.close()
    con.close()
    return user_sub, user_data_check


def check_subscribe(m):
    data = get_info(m)
    data_check = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    if data[0] != 'No':
        if data[1] <= data_check:
            con = POOL.connection()
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute('UPDATE users SET user_data = "Unlimit", user_sub = "No" WHERE user_id = %s',
                        (m.from_user.id,))
            con.commit()
            cur.close()
            con.close()
            bot.send_message(m.chat.id, text=constants.end_subscribe,
                             parse_mode="Markdown", disable_web_page_preview=True)
```

Сама ошибка:

```
 user_sub = data[0][3]
 IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Что дает cur.fethall:

```
((312, id, 'user_name', 'type_subscribe', 'data', None, 'None', None, None),)
```

Comment: Ну если например user_id подать такой, что его не будет в БД - получите свою ошибку. Всё дело в значениях m.from_user.id

Comment: Проверьте len(data) после fetchall, и сделайте raise с своим исключением при его значении == 0  - так будет правильней.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Но бот изначально регистрирует, а потом уже проверяет на подписку когда нажимаешь на кнопку.

Comment: кто мешает прислать Вашему боту какую нибудь фигню "извне"?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Данные m.from_user.id и прочее с (m.) это данные телеграмма, которые я получаю о пользователе. А остальные данные беру из  config файла.

Comment: Значит  логика бота позволяет сделать запрос к get_infо без предварительной __завершенной__ регистрации в БД.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич как это **завершенной** регистрации? после вставки данных я сохраняю изменения с помощью cur.commit()

Comment: не вижу всех исходников и логики работы Вашего бота в полном объеме, потому добавить ничего не могу. Указанная Вами ошибка с крайне высокой долей вероятности возникает по причине указанной выше.